# How start Spring project from cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I want to start project from cmd

The main method is:

```
package com.easytrip;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class EasyTripApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EasyTripApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I try to run it by:

```
javac EasyTripApplication.java
```

It throw next:

```
EasyTripApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                               ^
EasyTripApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
EasyTripApplication.java:5: error: package org.springframework.cache.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
                                           ^
EasyTripApplication.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
@EnableCaching
 ^
symbol: class EnableCaching
EasyTripApplication.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
EasyTripApplication.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        SpringApplication.run(EasyTripApplication.class, args);
        ^
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class EasyTripApplication
6 errors
```

I know that I must at first compile all external libraries, but how?

Comment: You really want to use an IDE, such as Eclipse (complex, actively maintained), Netbeans (simpler, maintenance is wait and see), or IntelliJ (commercial). Then, you probably want to use Maven or Gradle to build your project. Read up on those first.

Comment: @SeverityOne the [community edition of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) is free aswell =)

Comment: @Turing85 I thought the community edition of IntelliJ didn't support Spring Framework?

Comment: @TwiN this, I must admit, I did not check.

Comment: @Turing85 Finally, I win in an argument against you. Today might be Monday, but it's a good Monday: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: @TwiN Cookie? =)

Comment: The tag [tag:cmd] might be not applicable here unless you are really talking about Windows' `cmd.exe`...

Answer (score 2):

You can package it in a jar using `mvn clean package` and then run it with `java -jar your-application.jar`.

Alternatively, you can use the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) as a dependency and use `mvn spring-boot:run`.

If your application does not currently use Maven or Gradle, I urge you to consider using it as it will make your life significantly easier.

Answer (score 0):

As you're doing a Spring boot application you should be using either a Maven or Gradle to build the application.

Both of these tools will download all the required dependencies and produce an executable file you can run.

I'd recommend you start at https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/   It'll also be easier if you download the Spring Tool Suite which gives you a configured Eclipse environment as a head start.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set class path for all the libraries. Put all the jar file in to a folder like c:/java/lib and execute the `javac` command like below:-

```
javac -cp c:\java\lib\example1.jar;c:\java\lib\example2.jar  EasyTripApplication.java
```

Now while running the program

```
 java -cp c:\java\lib\example1.jar;c:\java\lib\example2.jar  EasyTripApplication
```

Also you can do it like below also
Windows

```
CP="c:\java\lib\example1.jar;c:\java\lib\example2.jar"

javac -cp %CP% EasyTripApplication.java
```

In Unix/Linux

```
 CP="/home/java/lib/example1.jar:/home/java/lib/example2.jar"

 javac -cp "$CP" EasyTripApplication.java
```